# setting ImageAdapter for retrieveing image

Tags: java, android, adapter

I am retrieving an image from Parse and having problem in setting image adapter. The problem is in last line of the `ImageAdapter` class
problem is in second last line and Image word after set is being red.

```
public ImeAdapter(Context context, List<Ime> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.ime_row_item, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mImes = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ime_row_item, null);
    }

    Ime ime = mImes.get(position);

    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ime_img);

    imgView.setImage(ime.getImg());
    return convertView;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, an ImageView doesn't have such method. What does `ime.getImg()` return?

Comment: for an imageView, you can use `setImageResource` or `setImageBitmap` or `setImageDrawable` to then assign the `ime.getImg()`. So it really depends on the type of iamge being returned from  your object. If it just a string that points to an image remotely hosted you will then have to download the image first, then proceed to assign it to your ImageView. There are a few libraries that will allow for this as well like Picasso or Glide.